# How to modify class source to annotate Kotlin class by custom Intellij Idea plugin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

How to write IntelliJ plugin that modify Kotlin class to annotate it with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` ?

I've tried the following code:

`KtPsiFactory(ktFile.project).createAnnotationEntry("@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)")`

but it throws

`0 declarations in @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) val x
java.lang.AssertionError: 0 declarations in @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) val x
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPsiFactory.createDeclaration(KtPsiFactory.kt:288)`

However it works for `@Ignore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah.. It should be `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`